# vba for connecting sheets and variables

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help if possible, on the following:

I have 2 workbooks, each one with the same sheets but each workbook has different data.
Sheets are named after the client they have data for.
i.e Sheet1 = John
Sheet 2 = Andrew etc.

In workbook2, I need to fill in some data from workbook 1, but to the correct sheet each time.
I mean, I want in workbook 2, at F32 to get the data that are in workbook 1 in cell T4, but for the same client.(sheet= john, will take the data that corresponds to sheet= john - of workbook1)
both workbooks have more than 100 sheets.
And I want to copy to the sheets of workbook b in cell F32 the data from workbook A cell T4 (but on each sheet , with the same sheetname)

On workbook B I have a template sheet that is beeing copied every time I need another sheet, so I would like to apply the code on the template
I don't know if I explain well what I need

Some very kind expert proposed this..

```
Dim workbookA as workbook, workbookB as workbook, sheetA as worksheet, sheetB as worksheet
Set workbookA = workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm")
Set workbookB = workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm")
Set sheetA = workbookA.Worksheets("sheetA")
Set sheetB = workbookA.Worksheets("sheetB")
sheetB.Range("F32").copy sheetA.Range("T4")
```

and it works (I changed some minor mistyped mistakes) but only if I set the name on each variable sheetA=workbookA.Worksheets("john")
sheetB = workbookB.Worksheets("john")

But I can't do that for 100 names and more

He also proposed to use :

> " If you have a list of worksheets you could make the worksheet variables dynamic:"

```
Set sheetB = workbooks.Worksheets(sheetA.Range("A2").Value)
```

etc

BUT i don't understand what I must do.
Can someone help me?
I don't know much about variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim workbookA As Workbook, workbookB As Workbook, sheetA As Worksheet, sheetB As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, sheetName As String
Set workbookA = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm")
Set workbookB = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm")

'Loop through each worksheet in Book A
For Each ws In workbookA.Worksheets
    Set sheetA = workbookA.Worksheets(ws.Name)
    Set sheetB = workbookB.Worksheets(ws.Name)
    sheetB.Range("F32").Copy sheetA.Range("T4")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I did exactly as you suggest and it returns the message :The cell you are trying to change is on a protected sheet, To make changes unprotect sheet.  BUT it is not a protected sheet and even f it was (where Workbook A is protected) the cell F32 where I want the value to be copied is an unlocked cell. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: The code you provided (and I worked off) is copying the value from WorkbookB Cell F32 INTO WorkbookA Cell T4, so if the sheet in WorkbookA is protected you will get the error. If you are trying to copy from WorkbookA into WorkbookB then change the line `sheetB.Range("F32").Copy sheetA.Range("T4")` to `sheetA.Range("F32").Copy sheetB.Range("T4")`